# Background Events ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, hangfire

I have an object with some event. For example:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.CustomEvent += _myEvent;

private void _myEvent(object sender, CustomEvent e)
{
   using (var db = new DbContext())
   {
      db.MyEntity.Add(e.Property);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

This event should be active all time application running.
For background tasks I use *Hangfire*. But my event not fired. Probably, there is no reason to use Hangfire for that problem at all.

Please help and thank you!

**Update**

I am doing Hangfire inside Startup.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double), new DoubleModelBinder());
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        .UseSqlServerStorage("myConString");
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyEventListener());
        app.UseHangfireServer();
    }

    public void MyEventListener()
    {
        new MyObject().CustomEvent += delegate (object sender, CustomEvents e)
        {
           using (var db = new DbContext())
           {
               db.MyEntity.Add(e.Property);
               db.SaveChanges();
           }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the code you've shown tries to register the event in a HangFire job. Hangfire would be a good solution to keep something running in the background, however you need to actually use it.

Comment: Thank you. I will edit my post to show it with Hangfire code.

Answer (score 1):

Hangfire has to serialize your jobs, then deserialize them at run time to invoke the logic you enqueued. If you simply want to attach an event to an object, then you don't necessarily need Hangfire for this.

In your example, attaching the event will be meaningless, because CustomEvent is an instance property so you are creating a new instance of the object. That instance will be out of scope as soon as you call MyEventListener. Additionally, all you've done is attached an event to a new unused instance of MyObject, but never invoked it.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I've already tried put my code in Global.asax or Startup without Hangfire, but it's not working. Where should i place my object with event? I want to keep it alive all time.

Comment: What do you want to happen and when? Your example as it is now will never fire the event. You're creating an instance of an object, attaching an event to that object, and then it goes out of scope never to be used again. You could attach the event in the object constructor, you could make the event a static property, but without understanding what you're trying to achieve, I can't say.